# Applying a defined function to lapply

Tags: r, function, csv

I have defined a function that I want to apply to a list of datasets but I get errors and can't figure out why. I tried debugging my code and still don't know what's wrong with it. My function is :

```
lire<-function(element){ 
    d=read.csv(file="element.csv", sep=';', header=FALSE, dec = ",",
    col.names= c("Action", "Date", "Ouverture", "Haut","Bas","Cloture","VolumeEch")) 
    return(d) 
}
```

I want to apply it like this:

```
L <- lapply(Sys.glob("*.csv"), function(x) lire(x))
```

Comment: `paste0(element, ".csv")`

Comment: I still get wrapup errors

Comment: edited the post so that the code is formatted.

Comment: if you don't tell us what the errors are, not only do we have no way of helping you, but we are averse to doing so due to a lack of demonstrated effort

Comment: MichaelChirico I thought I was being precise when I said "wrap up errors". That's exacly what the terminal displayed as errors. Take it easy on my I'm fairly new to R .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works fine:

```
lire<-function(element){ 
  read.csv(file=element, sep=';', header=FALSE, dec = ",",
             col.names= c("Action", "Date", "Ouverture", "Haut","Bas","Cloture","VolumeEch")) 
}
```

`element` will consecutively take every value from `Sys.glob("*.csv")`. Assigning to `d` and return are unnecessary.